# Cucumber: creating a step definition that compares two categories

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, ruby-on-rails-3.1, cucumber

I have a step in one of my cucumber features called

`Then the director of "Alien" should be "Ridley Scott"`

And I created my step definition as follows

```
Then /^the director of "([^"]*)" should be "([^"]*)"$/ do |arg1, arg2|
  Movie.find_by_title(arg1) == Movie.find_by_director(arg2)
end
```

Which passes the test but I don't believe it is truly correct. Any suggestions on implementing proper functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

```
Movie.find_by_title(arg1).director == arg2
```